# Username suggestion for new signups

Tags: feature-request, new-users, display-names

I'm getting used to Stack Overflow lately and wanted to get involved more.

My first contribution to Meta SO is that I want to suggest the usernames of newly signed up users. Their default username is like `username2345678` and seeing all of these numbers floating all over is quite un-human.

So, Stack Overflow can either ask them nicely to update their profile information first, or by default set their email address prefix to the username.

Like:
`myname@stackoverflow.com` fetch `myname` part and set it to "default" username.

It's just a suggestion, though.

Answer (score 17):

Sure, let's expose personally identifying information of people, without asking them.

Not a good idea - in particular given that this can easily allow others to guess the email address from the username. ("`myname` - let's try `myname@gmail.com`, `myname@hotmail.com`...")

Comment: Im not asking the exact strategy. this could be anything else. Just to avoid the `username{ID}` kind of stuff

Comment: @yaqoob - what's a better suggestion then? You gave one that is really not great. And I don't agree with your assessment of the current process being "unhuman".

Comment: OpenID/Social Signups have First Or Last names, you can choose their names?

Comment: @yaqoob - that doesn't address the privacy matter at all. The names used have to be random and not based on anything the user provides.

Comment: @yaqoob My name is neither my email address or my real name.  I don't need/want anyone trying to guess who I am because - well, I don't really care, but why publishing personal info when you don't need too.  So why should SE propose a default user name that will expose personal info without the user explicitly doing that himself

Comment: @Stilly.stack maybe it is a good example... maybe 2003 is completely meaningless, and not related to a significant milestone in my life.

Comment: @psubsee If I thot of everyone on the internet as being born in 2003 for no reason… wow that's an amazing perspective. :P

Comment: @bjb568 Wait, wait, back up. There are people on the Internet who _weren't_ born in 2003? Where did you find them???

Comment: @Oblivious I think there is a jQuery plugin for that.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not saying I like your suggestion, but in an attempt to address @Oded's valid concerns, consider this option:

Like the Gravatar, use a hash of the email address to assemble a couple words from a dictionary.

So running this on myself, I would be named **niblike collegiality**

I agree **user123456** is boring, but don't honestly feel a very strong need to do something different. It's just a consideration *if* this were desired. One main benefit this has over **user123456** is easier recognition on seeing a user again. I'm not convinced that's a necessity though.

Sincerely yours,
niblike collegiality

Comment: Hey, that sounds good. Like an automatic avatar (identicon).